# Can't access window object property in Nuxt (Vue) mounted

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tron, tronweb, tronlink

I have a **TronLink** chrome extension, this extension provides a `window.tronWeb` property and I want to access this property after document load. I am trying to do that in the `mounted()` section of my Nuxt page component:

```
// ...
mounted() {
  this.tronWeb = window.tronWeb;
},
// ...
```

but I receive `undefined`.

I have resolved this problem with a timeout:

```
// ...
mounted() {
  let _this = this;

  let attempts = 0;
  setTimeout(function startGame() {
    if (window.tronWeb) {
      _this.tronWeb = window.tronWeb;
    } else {
      attempts++;
      if (attempts >= 5) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        setTimeout(startGame, 500);
      }
    }
  }, 0);
},
// ...
```

But it looks like this a very strange solution. Why can't I access this property directly in the `mounted()` section?

Comment: If this exenstion is executing and adding this variable to windows with delay then timeout look like suitable solution for me. I would just check if nextTick would make any difference.

Comment: Maybe the extension executes its code after the `mounted` function.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
if (process.browser) {
  console.log('The window object:', window)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may refer to :
[nuxt docs > ssr section > window is not defined](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering#window-or-document-undefined)

because this code is rendered in the server, you can't access the window object.

you may use the `process.client` to check and run the code only on the client-side

```
if (process.client){
   console.log('do sth')
}
```